Possible bug in MSVC Version 17.11.3 compiler pertaining to integer literal types?
I'm using VS2022 with the version 17.11.3 compiler on Win10 64-bit and my code is below followed by its output.  My understanding is that the type of an integer literal expressed in decimal with no suffix is the first of types int, long, and long long that can accommodate the value.  If that is the case, I believe the value of sizeof(2147483648) should be 8 and not 4, it and is indeed 8 if I switch to the clang compiler that comes with VS2022.  If this is a bug, is it worth trying to report it to Microsoft?
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "LONG_MAX = " << LONG_MAX << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(long) = " << sizeof(long) << "\n";
    cout << "LLONG_MAX = " << LLONG_MAX << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(long long) = " << sizeof(long long) << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(2147483647) = " << sizeof(2147483647) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(2147483648) = " << sizeof(2147483648) << "\n";
}

Output:
LONG_MAX = 2147483647
sizeof(long) = 4
LLONG_MAX = 9223372036854775807
sizeof(long long) = 8

sizeof(2147483647) = 4
sizeof(2147483648) = 4


Are you compiling for x64? The output looks like it's for x32. For x64 (from what I know, can be wrong), the sizeof(long) and sizeof(long long) should be same.

Side note : use std::numeric_limits<long>()::max not LONG_MAX. And no I would not report it as a bug. Also next time make sure you have a fully compilable example which would allow us to show you what's happening in for example compiler explorer (godbolt.org)

2147483648 is unsigned int, not long long.

#3CxEZiVlQ  Your contention that the decimal literal 2147483648 is an unsigned of any type disagrees with section 2.14.2.2 of the C++11 standard and section 5.13.2.3 of the C++23 standard.

@BenevolentDeity "is it worth trying to report it to Microsoft?..." No, you just need to just /permissive- flag for standard conformance.

Always use /permissive- flag with msvc so that you're sure you're compiling the program with standard conformance.

See Microsoft C/C++: what is the definition of "strict conformance" w.r.t. implementation?

Also note that /permissive- is implied by /std=c++20. If you compile for older standards (like C++14), you get it "like it used to be" (non-conformance. and all).

@kiner_shah On Windows, long remains 32-bit even in x64 builds. Quoting MS docs: "In particular, long is 4 bytes even on 64-bit operating systems." See also this answer.

@heapunderrun interesting, thanks for the links.

Visual Studio latest version is 17.11.4.
sizeof(2147483648) is 8.
So you don't need to report this issue. And update your Visual Studio.



I updated to version is 17.11.4, but still produced the wrong answer.  I then created an entirely new project, and it worked correctly.  I don't know what might have caused this issue in the original project so I'll have to spend some time looking around a bit :-)


is it worth trying to report it to Microsoft?

No, you just need to use the /permissive- flag for standard conformance.
Demo
As you can see in the demo above, the output is 8 when we use the /permissive- flag.
